# Angularjs Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I'm not able to figure out why I'm getting the module error which I get when I don't inject required modules. Here's a link to my plunker.
[Plunker-UserApp](http://plnkr.co/edit/RL0MXM?p=preview)

Here's the full error from my browser console.

VM677 angular.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=myapp&p1=Error%3A%2…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.5%2Fangular.min.js%3A37%3A180)

I'm trying to create a User App which procures Users from a mocker.io website which holds the json objects.

### About User App:

It performs 3 tasks.

1. Get User List from the mocker and display it as a table
2. Create and add a new user
3. Get a user based on  the id

The above mentioned tasks are implemented in the service "userService". This service is then injected into the controller components which are written in  "UserListController.js" and "AddUserController.js". The module is defined in the script.js along with the routing config. The user list view and add new user view are in their own separate templates.

### UserService.js

```
//An Angular Service to retreive UserList from the backend
(function() {
  angular.module('myapp')
    .service('userService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
      var usrSvc = this;

      //Function to get User List from the backend
      usrSvc.getUserList = function() {

        var defer = $q.defer();

        $http
          .get('http://mocker.egen.io/users')
          .then(function(response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            defer.resolve(response.data);
          }, function(error) {
            console.log(error.status);
            defer.reject(error.status);
          });
        return defer.promise;
      };

      usrSvc.addUser = function(newUser) {
        var defer = $q.defer();

        $http
          .post('http://mocker.egen.io/users', newUser)
          .then(function(response) {
            defer.resolve(response.status);
            console.log(response);
          }, function(error) {
            defer.reject(error.status);
            console.log(error);
          });
        //return defer.promise;
      };

    }]);
})();
```

### AddUserController.js

```
(function(){
  angular
    .module('myapp')
    .controller('AddUserCtrl',AddUserCtrlfn);

    AddUserCtrlfn.$inject = ['userService'];

    function AddUserCtrlfn(userService){
      var addUserVm = this;

      userService.addUser(addUserVm.formData)
      .then(function(promiseStatus){
        alert('Success! User created!');
        console.log(promiseStatus);
      }, function(errorStatus){
        alert('An error occurred while creating the user');
        console.log(errorStatus);
      });
    }
})();
```

### UserListController.js

```
(function() {
  angular.module('myapp')
    .controller('UserListCtrl', UserListCtrlfn);

    UserListCtrlfn.$inject = ['userService'];

    function UserListCtrlfn(userService) {
      var UserListVm = this;
      userService.getUserList()
        .then(function(promiseObj) {
          UserListVm.users = promiseObj;
        }, function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change order of `<script>` tag in order to define your module at first before use it.

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
<script src="UserListController.js"></script>
<script src="AddUserController.js"></script>
<script src="UserService.js"></script>
```

And [remove first argument in `config` method](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#config).

Comment: Thank you Very much! It worked. I got a new error after that which got solved after I removed my ng-controller from my UserList template.